# function won't execute (correctly) more than once

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to change the position of a div following these guidlines to make it look fluid:

- very small increments at a time
- numerous times per second
- at a given angle(hence all the trig in endpoint())

I have tested my function, "endpoint()", which handles the calculation and movement of the div and it works as intended.  However, when I try to execute the function more than once, it doesn't work.

```
<style type="text/css">
.ball
{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#00c0c6;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
</style>

<div id="tehBall" class="ball"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    endpoint(slopeInRadians); //WORKS!  (changes position of the div)
    endpoint(slopeInRadians); //DOESN'T work (doesn't change the position of the div)
    endpoint(slopeInRadians); //DOESN'T work (same as above)
</script>
```

here is the code for endpoint function:

```
function endpoint(m) 
{
    var oldX = getStyle("tehBall", "left");
    var oldY = getStyle("tehBall", "top");

    var xAxis = parseInt(oldX);
    var yAxis = parseInt(oldY); 

    var dX = (Math.cos(m));
    var dY = ((0 - Math.sin(m))); 

    xAxis += dX;
    yAxis += dY;

    xAxis = xAxis.toString();
    yAxis = yAxis.toString();   

    xAxis += "px";
    yAxis += "px";

    document.getElementById('tehBall').style.left = xAxis;
    document.getElementById('tehBall').style.top = yAxis;   

}
```

code for getStyle(used in endpoint function):

```
function getStyle(id, property){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var value = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue(property);


    return value;
}
```

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: anybody know why the function won't change the position of the div multiple times when it is executed multiple times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of working on the style, just store the coordinates in global variables, like so:

Remember to round the value when you put it into a style, since not all (older) browsers support floating point.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xAxis =0.0;
var yAxis = 0.0;
function endpoint(m) 
{
    var dX = (Math.cos(m)/* * d*/);
    var dY = ((0 - Math.sin(m))/* * d*/); 

    xAxis += dX;
    yAxis += dY;

    document.getElementById('tehBall').style.left = Math.round(xAxis) + 'px';
    document.getElementById('tehBall').style.top = Math.round(yAxis) + 'px';   

}
</script>
```

Comment: is it the repeated retrieval of the style's property value that is causing the function to hang? if so, is there a known work around? I understand there is no direct need for it here, however I would like to know for the future.  many thanks!

Comment: The problem in the above script seems to be the use of `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat`, since you are losing all your precision :) I hope that answers your question.

Comment: oh, thank you!  that makes a lot of sense, I don't know why I didn't see that before